# Position elements horizontally with TailwindCSS

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css

So i am using Tailwindcss and laravel and in this page i am trying to position products horizontally in the page according to their category

Here's the products list
[image: Product list vertical]

So to put them horizontally, i tried using the class="flex flex-wrap content-start space-x-2"
But the width changes and becomes like that.
[image: Product list horizontal]

Here's the code :
[image: Code]

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
```

{{ $category->title }} id) }}">(Voir tout les produits)

    @foreach ($category->products as $product)

```
{{-- <div>{{ $product->title }}</div> --}}

        <div class="mt-5">
            
                <div class="max-w-sm mx-auto rounded-md shadow-md overflow-hidden">
                    <div class="flex items-end justify-end h-56 w-full bg-cover" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563170351-be82bc888aa4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=376&q=80')">
                        <button class="p-2 rounded-full bg-blue-600 text-white mx-5 -mb-4 hover:bg-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:bg-blue-500">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path d="M3 3h2l.4 2M7 13h10l4-8H5.4M7 13L5.4 5M7 13l-2.293 2.293c-.63.63-.184 1.707.707 1.707H17m0 0a2 2 0 100 4 2 2 0 000-4zm-8 2a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0z"></path></svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="px-5 py-3">
                        <h3 class="text-gray-700">{{ $product->title }}</h3>
                        <span class="text-gray-500 mt-2">{{ $product->price }} DA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    
    
@endforeach
```

@endforeach

Comment: Please prefer posting actual text rather than a screenshot of your code.

Comment: Hello Kissu, i added the code.

Comment: Hi, my example still do not work ?

Comment: Hello, no it's not working but i found the solution i had to change the way that the foreach loop was used so i can get the elements in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

`flex flex-col items-center` should be enough here on the "max-w-sm div".

Here is a working demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/NMps4Dr0m0

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer but that's not what i want, i want to align them horizontally.

Comment: My example do align the elements horizontally btw.